# How to justify computing real integrals with complex integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

For just a bit of background... I'm familiar with *how* to compute real integrals using complex integrals. But I'm a bit concerned with the logical legitimacy of it.

For example, to compute the real integral (real as in the Riemann integral defined over the set $\mathbb{R}$)

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty {\frac{1}{(x^2 + 1)^2} } dx$$
We eventually end up computing instead the complex integral 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty {\frac{1}{(z^2 + 1)^2} }dz $$
along the "real line" embedded in $\mathbb{C}$.

This may sound a bit nitpicky... what exactly are the steps involved in going from saying that the complex integral evaluates to $\pi/2$ and that the real integral evaluates to $\pi/2$?

I know model theory deals with the embedding of structures within other structures. But it too seems restricted in saying only stuff regarding particular models which we consider to "be" $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I think you're using the term "model theory" wrongly.

Comment: Since the reals are a subfield of the complex numbers, any computation with real numbers gives the same result as the same computation with those numbers considered as complex numbers.  Since the absolute value of a real number is its absolute value as a complex number, a limit of real numbers is the same whether you consider these as real or complex numbers.  An integral is expressed in terms of limits of expressions...

Comment: Logical law of substitution. If you're talking about z as any deformed path between $-\infty$ and $\infty$ that does not cross the pole at i, I don't know but I think it's a subtly different question.

Comment: @ClementYung Can you clarify? I see that embedding is most definitely a model theoretic concept https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Embedding_(Model_Theory)

Comment: @RobertIsrael I think I get it now, not sure how I missed it. Following your logic I convinced myself with a simpler analogy: this is effectively like proving $1+1=2$ (in reals) by computing $(1+0i)+(1+0i)=2+0i$ (in embedded reals). However you compute the complex integral, in general it has the same value as the real one (up to the embedding) so the answer is the same. If you could post it as answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Posted as an answer at the OP's request]

Since the reals are a subfield of the complex numbers, any computation with real numbers gives the same result as the same computation with those numbers considered as complex numbers. Since the absolute value of a real number is its absolute value as a complex number, a limit of real numbers is the same whether you consider these as real or complex numbers. An integral is expressed in terms of limits of expressions...